# Querying 2 cells from each partition in cassandra using cql

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am new to cassandra, I am using cassandra datastax driver to access my keyspace. I have a legacy table which is created by using cassandra thrift client. I am in need of retrieving two column values from each partion in one query. It is like multigetslice Query in hector api. How can I do this using cql and DataStax Java driver?

**--edit--**

My column family is a legacy table, which looks like the following in cqlsh.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  key blob,
  column1 text,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key), column1)
).
```

I need to select two values for each key. In this table i used to store messages of each user. userid as rowkey, messageid as columnname and message as value. I need to show two latest messages from each user.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your column family definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [IN filter condition](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectIN).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should execute one request per partition (execute concurrently if getting more than one parition). Assuming you want the top two in the natural order of 'column1':

```
SELECT column1, value FROM messages WHERE key=<blob> LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: I want one query to get the expected result. Like multigetslice query in hector. anybody know how hector queries in multigetslice query method?